# character encoding problem on servlet

Tags: string, file, servlets, encoding, character

Why is it that when I call this method inside a servlet (either get or post)

```
public void read () throws IOException
{   
    try{
      File file = new File ("/text.txt");
      BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                              (new FileInputStream(file),"UTF8"));
      String str1;
      while ((str1 = i.readLine()) != null)   {
          // Print the content on the console
          System.out.println (str1);
        } 

     }


      catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ue){

       System.out.println("Not supported : ");

  }
}
```

the console spits out question marks on all the japanese and arabic characters. However, calling this method from a class with a main method, the console spits out the japanese and arabic characters just fine. I am using websphere application server on rational application developer.

Note, the method is not in the servlet, but is part of another class.

Answer (score 1):

> the console spits out question marks on all the japanese and arabic characters

You need to configure the console to use a charset which covers those characters.

How to do that depends on who's managing the console. If it's for example Eclipse, then you can do that by setting *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding* to UTF-8.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Servlet response, you need to set the headers correctly. Something similar to following.

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

check for correct charset for japanse and arabic characters.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that, but yes I did place that line as the first call in the get method and that doesn't work

Comment: Copy and paste your servlet code (get/post method) or source content from browser. Makesure you have used utf-8 instead of utf8. Most people make mistake one missing -.

Comment: protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {


  res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  
  CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter ();
  writer.read();
}

That is basically it. The CsvWriter class contains that read method. Really bugs me that something so simple doesn't want to work. When I call the read method via a main method, everything is okay, but here it is not